# CATransition animation gets crashed sometimes

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uitableview, catransition

I am using a CATransition animation in my application and it works fine, but crashes some times.

This is my Code:

```
-(void)_close_btn_click:(UIButton*)button
{

  NSLog(@"update Button %ld clicked.",(long int)[button tag]);    
  NSInteger intvalue=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long int)[button tag]]intValue];    
  NSLog(@"delete_index:%d",intvalue);    
  CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];    
  [transition setDuration:1.0];    
  transition.type = @"rippleEffect";    
  transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;    
  transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];    

  [cell._slide_view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"push-transition"];    
  CATransition* transition1 = [CATransition animation];    
  [transition1 setDuration:1.0];    
  transition1.type = @"rippleEffect";    
  transition1.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;    
  [cell._en_cell_close_btn.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"push-transition"];
  cell._slide_view.hidden=YES;    
}
```

Comment: Crash log, exception name, anything?

Comment: I really don't understand, why people write code like this : `NSInteger intvalue=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long int)[button tag]]intValue];`

Answer (score 1):

I guess maybe your `cell` or `_slide_view` has been deallocated before you call this method